# Anylogic query How to select values from a databse table after interpolation

Tags: java, sql, interpolation, querydsl, anylogic

I have a database table with 2 columns in Anylogic. I would like to know query dsl code or the sql code for selecting a value from the table in column2 after comparing my input with the values of column 1 and after doing linear interpolation. 
My code in Anylogic provides a value `x2 where (x1 < x2 < x3`) and `x2` is not in the table.  and I want to select from the table a value `y2` based on `x2 where (y1 < y2 < y3)` and `y2` is not in the table. So I would like to make the software interpolate and return the value `y2` as follows after looking up in the table:

```
y2= [(x2-x1)*(y3-y1)/(x3-x1)]+y1

x1  |  y1

x3  |  y2

x4  |  y3

x5  |  y4
```

Example: If my code returns `x=0.15` I would like the program to interpolate and return from the table the value y where:

```
y =[[0.15-0.1]*(0.0072-0.0127)/(0.2-0.1)]+0.0127= 0.00995

---x  |   y

0.1  | 0.0127

0.2  | 0.0072

0.3  | 0.0039

0.4  | 0.0020

0.5  | 0.0010

0.3  | 0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting values from the built-in database table and doing linear interpolation with them, you may simply create a table function and configure it to load data from the database.

Since linear interpolation is chosen as the function interpolation type by default, you just need to call `tableFunction(0.15)` to get `y = 0.00995` for `x = 0.15`.